# How to batchGet index table in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

How to batchGet global secondary index in DynamoDB?

---

These params gives me a schema error because this hash key is only in index table, main has other.

```
  const params = {
    RequestItems: {
      "MyTableName": {
        Keys: [
           {
              "ThisHashKeyIsOnlyInIndexTable": value
           }
        ]
      }
    }
  };
  
  docClient.batchGet(params, (err, data) => {
    // ...
  }
```

Docs doesn't even mention how to batchGet only from index(es).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `GetItem` and `BatchGetItem`, can not access any indexes. You can't pass `IndexName` on params similar to Query API.

Highlighted the point relevant to the question.

> ReturnConsumedCapacity — (String) Determines the level of detail about
>   provisioned throughput consumption that is returned in the response:
>
> INDEXES - The response includes the aggregate ConsumedCapacity for the
>   operation, together with ConsumedCapacity for each table and secondary
>   index that was accessed. **Note that some operations, such as GetItem
>   and BatchGetItem, do not access any indexes at all. In these cases,
>   specifying INDEXES will only return ConsumedCapacity information for
>   table(s).**
>
> TOTAL - The response includes only the aggregate ConsumedCapacity for
>   the operation. NONE - No ConsumedCapacity details are included in the
>   response.