# boto3 dynamodb batch_get_item in index not working

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a working boto3 dynamodb query below:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('gpc')
    video_id = 25
    response = table.query(
        IndexName='skuindex',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('sku').eq('98123')
    )
    print(response)
```

Which will look inside my table 'gpc', inside the index 'skuindex' for rows where sku=98123. It returns one result correctly.

I am trying to replicate this query in a `batch_get_item` command, but am unable to query for the sku field, and can't figure out how to specify the index.

The following `batch_get_item` code works:

```
boto3.resource('dynamodb')
dynamo = boto3.client("dynamodb", region_name="us-east-1")
serializer = boto3.dynamodb.types.TypeSerializer().serialize

test_keys = [] 
test_keys.append({
    "upc": serializer("8122222"), 
    #"sku": serializer("98123"), 
    "source_store": serializer("itemname_itemname")
}) 
test_response = dynamo.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems={
        "gpc": {'Keys': test_keys}
    }
)
print("len(test_response['Responses']['gpc']) = ", len(test_response['Responses']['gpc']))
```

Is there some way I can specify inside this above to use the 'skuindex' index? Is that even possible with the batch_get_item command? If i uncomment the sku line, it leads to an error:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchGetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema`

Because the sku field is only accessible in the 'skuindex' index apparently. I've tried adding index specific code to the batch_get_item query with no success.

How can I tell my batch_get_item to look inside the 'skuindex' index of my 'gpc' table?

Answer (score 4):

Rafael Almeida's answer, saying that `BatchGetItem` (and also `GetItem`) cannot read using an index is correct. He said it is a **DynamoDB limitation**, but I think it's interesting to understand why using an index simply doesn't fit the `GetItem` or `BatchGetItem` request API, but does fit `Query`:

One important difference between the `Query` request and `GetItem`/`BatchGetItem` requests is that `Query` API is designed to be able to return an unbounded number of responses. `Query` is therefore designed around the notion of *paging* and its ability to get back any number of items. In contrast, `GetItem` will always return one item (or none), while `BatchGetItem` can return more - but they will all be stuck in a single response.

Now, the thing is that the nature of an index is that you can never know how many items will actually match your lookup **sku=98123**. Your application assumes it will be just one, but nothing actually prevents it from storing a million items, all having the same **sku** value. An item's key needs to be unique, but nothing guarantees that a non-key attribute is unique.

So, if DynamoDB were to allow a `GetItem` with an index lookup **sku=98123**, it would need to somehow be able to return - potentially - either one or a million different results. Basically, Amazon would have needed to add support for `Limit` and paging to `GetItem` - but there is already a request that had exactly such support built-in, and that was `Query`. This is why you need to do index queries through `Query`.

You are right - it means you can do multiple such reads in one request. There is no `BatchQuery` request. But to be honest, a `BatchGetItem` didn't need to exist either - users should have been able to send a stream of separate `GetItem` or `Query` requests on the same connection. This could have just as efficient as today's `BatchGetItem` if DynamoDB used HTTP/2 - which finally added proper support for request pipelining (and out-of-order responses). Maybe one day DynamoDB will support HTTP/2 (as far as I know, it still doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way I can specify inside this above to use the 'skuindex' index?

Unfortunately, you can’t, and this is not a `boto3` limitation but [a DynamoDB limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501001/how-to-batchget-index-table-in-dynamodb).