# Python Pandas dataframe does contain all values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boto3

I've been trying to read data from a dynamodb database using Boto3 in python. After collecting all the data i write everything to a csv file on our local server. After writing the "raw" data of database i use again the data frame but it looks like its missing some Columns Looking at the first exported csv it contains 85 columns which is correct.But the second file only has 66? Have no clue why 19 columns dissapeard somehow.Here is the code:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

#Export Raw data
#Dynamodb client connection instance
dynamo_client = boto3.resource(...)

#List services by resource
dynamo_client.get_available_subresources()

#Testing connection with table
vopak_table = dynamo_client.Table('vopakdata2')
print(vopak_table.table_status)

#Get all items from Dynamodb
response = vopak_table.scan()
data = response['Items']

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = vopak_table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])
    
#Write data to CSV 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Time column first in sheet
first_column = df.pop('time')
df.insert(0,'time',first_column)
#Save as CSV
df.to_csv(r'C:\export.csv',index=False, header=True)

#MMA Calculation
#Remove hours from timestamp
df['time'] = df['time'].astype("datetime64").dt.date
#Use time as index
df = df.set_index("time")
#Add the MMA columns
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])

#Save as CSV
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
df = df.to_csv(r'C:\exportMMA.csv', index=False,header=True)
```

Comment: your agg operation likely reduces the values. try commenting it out and see if you still see the row loss

Comment: When debugging i find out that from line 26: df = pd.DataFrame(data). The problem occurs. And my agg operation uses the df but the columns are already reduced...

Comment: hmm, not sure. boto3 uses pagination and partitioning in some modules but I wouldn't expect that to be an issue with such a low row count... have you tried uploading a test table and then running through this same process? could be that there is something funky going on with that particular table (corrupted records?). [for example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html)

Comment: Yea i tried yesterday with diffrent tables, all the same exporting it "raw" no problems, When manupilating data it's getting funky.

Comment: I can't say I'm familiar with the dynamodb module in boto3 but that would be my next step in debugging --> trying different access methods. maybe scan() is only returning the head of your table. [maybe using table.query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121806/boto3-dynamodb-batch-get-item-in-index-not-working). I'm guessing at this point so take this with a grain of salt

Comment: The problem occurs when adding the 'mean' column in the .agg function. Min Max works just fine. Really have no clue what is causing this. Adding another column like for exmaple ['min','max','sum'] results in the correct output